# SVN for XCode Project

Tags: svn

I am looking for sub version solution for iPhone applications (xCode Projects). i have tried Rapid SVN and SCPlugin but both plugins are not so use full and it behaved randomly like giving error like "file is locked" etc.. So is there any powerful solution for same. One more think i am not able to figure out that why only few files are updated while taking SVN update, same with SVN commit.

can you all give some helpful information on same?

Thanks in Advance

Vivek Navadia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode has builtin support for Subversion. If you open the preferences (COMMAND+COMMA), and then go to the tab named "SCM", you can configure Xcode to integrate with Subversion. That said, my own personal preference is to just use the commandline.... that way, you actually know what Subversion commands are being executed, which is really nice given that the Subversion Book talks about the commands, themselves, and not about how some particular GUI or IDE chooses to map its interactions to Subversion commands.

If only a few files are being committed or updated, probably forgot to issue "svn add" to place those files under version control; Subversion only manages the files that you tell it to manage.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for solution, i will check this. can you please post usage guideline of same if any.